# I cannot find where the static blocks are stacking up from on my home page

Tags: magento, block

```
   <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
            <label>Page Header</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            <block type="core/template" name="pageHeader" template="page/html/topcontainer.phtml">
                <block type="core/template" name="page.header" template="page/html/page_header.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
            </block>
        </block>
```

This block lines up my entire home page. I need to add another block in to this list. This is read from CMS blocks in Admin panel. How can I find the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code you will be able to read from CMS blocks in Admin panel with name contact.

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="contact" before="-">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>contact</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can find the blocks from the admin panel. But I cannot find where the blocks are defined for "page/html_wrapper".